# how to make custom calendar by using horizontal list view in android

Tags: android

I'm beginner android developer.

I want to make horizontal calendar of current year.

I'm using this [link](http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2012/11/horizontal-listview-in-android-example.html) for horizontal list view but I got some problem.

Current date of this month shown at 1st index and remaining previous date subtract from calendar.

When scroll horizontally if previous month end then start new month with name in this list.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). Also use [LinearLayoutManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html) with Horizontal Flag

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Or if you want a ready library you can use One of this

[Android Week View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View)

[KBCalendar-Android](https://github.com/Kevin-Bernage/KBCalendar-Android)